# Save information from NSTextField in sqlite database (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

Since some months I am interested in coding. At the moment I am working on a programm which saves informations from textfields in a sqlite3 database. I am programming this project on Objective C in Xcode for Mac. Unfortunately I have problems in inserting data into my database. When I insert it and open my database in Terminal I just get this information in the cell for the string:

Here ist my code:

```
NSString *Bt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Text]; //Theres a IBOutlet NSTextField  *Text; in the Header data of the class


dbPath=@"/Users/Desktop/database.db";

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)!=SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
} else {
    char *errorMessage;
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO table (table) VALUES (\"%@\")", Bt];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_exec(database, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Data inserted");
        [db_status setFloatValue:5];
    }

}
```

}

It would be great if somebody can help me. I think it is just a small error but  I don´t get the problem ;(

Best regards,
Robby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the looks of your `IBOUTLET` connection, how you have your code, **Bt** is equal to the **TextField**. But what you want is the text value in the **TextField**. so you would use this: `NSString *Bt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Text.stringValue];` **NSTextField** has a property named **stringValue** and this will return the **NSString** that contains the value inside the textfield, **Text**.

### Allowing Quotation Marks in Your Database

So easiest way, i can think of, is having a category method on NSString. So wherever you're going to save string or text from the user to your database, you would use this function to then insert into your format statement. and example shown below:

**Header File of NSString Category**

```
@interface NSString (STRING_)

/**
 * Allowing Qoutation marks inside a string to be saved in a SQL column with the string format sourrounded by @"\"%@\"". this will not modify the string, only return a modified copy
 * @return NSString *
 */
- (NSString *)reformatForSQLQuries;

@end
```

**Implantation File of NSString Category**

```
@implementation NSString (STRING_)

- (NSString *)reformatForSQLQuries {
    NSString *string = self;
    //Depending on how you "wrap" your strings to format the string values into your INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries, you'll only have to use one of these statements. YOU DO NOT NEED BOTH

    //Use this if you have your format as: '%@'
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"'" withString: @"''"];
    //Use this if you have your format as: \"%@\"
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\"" withString: @"\"\""];

    return string;

}
```

**example**

```
...
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO table (table) VALUES (\"%@\")", [Bt reformatForSQLQuries]];
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response ! When I add your code I get this error message:  No visible @interface for ´NSString´ declares the selector ´reformForSQLQuries´.

Comment: Now it works ;) I forgot to import the class header ;) Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution ! It´s false to write:

```
NSString *Bt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Text];
```

The solution is to get the value from the NSTextField:

```
NSString *Bt = [NSTextField stringValue];
```

What I still don´t understand is why it´s not possible to save Strings which include this symbol: "". For example:

The database saves this: I like programming.
But not this: I like "programming".

Can somebody explain me why ?

Comment: You just have to write a string method to replace the character " with this "" for every single time there is a " so the string you would save would be: I like ""programming""

Comment: Why you can't just have: I like "programming" is bc the compiler thinks that is the end of the string when it sees a " character. Like when you write `NSString *words = @"hello there, "Bob"";` that is not going to work. Instead you'd use this `NSString *words = @"hello there, \"Bob\"";`

Comment: Thank you for your response ! What I don´t understand is how to use your program codes in general. I try to get the text from a NSTextField. I don´t know if the user uses "" characters or not. How should I write your solution in general into my code ?

Comment: Ooh yeah! I have a category function you can use, simple and it works :)

Comment: check out the answer shown in this question to answer your question on using quotation marks in SQL. let me know if you need any explaining :)